# What does 'commission' mean in this context?

Tags: idioms

> Ashley works at a nearby electronics store. She **makes a commission** of
>   7% on everything she sells. If she sells a computer for $329.00,
>   how much money does Ashley **make in commission**?

I have searched the idiom in many dictionaries.. but i can't understand perfectly..
How should i understand the idiom in this context?

Comment: I was surprised to find this is not a British usage. You want to look in dictionaries of American English for *commission*: for instance, [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/commission), definition 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commission is the amount of money that she earns when she sells an item. In your case is 7% of the products's price.